# Django: [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

Tags: django, modelform, formset

I have a modelformset that I want to save to a model.

In my templates, the following works perfectly (meaning that the form saves to the database when I hit submit):

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{{ formset }}
```

Even this works great:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for row in formset %}
    {{ row }}
{% endfor %}
```

But as soon as I want to style my formset (in a table) like so:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for row in formset %}
    {{ row.field1 }}
    {{ row.field2 }}
    {{ row.field3 }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'].

Fields 1 to 3 corresponds exactly to the model I want to save to.  I really cannot figure this out!

My traceback shows this:

```
GET    No GET data
POST   Variable              Value
       form-0-field1         u'3'
       form-0-field2         u'3'
       form-0-field3         u'3'
```

Which are the same values I used in the first two examples (and which saved correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Your rendering of the form doesn't include the additional data which are required for the ManagementForm (`form-TOTAL_FORMS`, `form-INITIAL_FORMS` and `form-MAX_NUM_FORMS`)

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Railslide.  I'm not sure why this would work in the first 2 examples, but not for the third?  I also tested by excluding the last {{ row.field3 }} and it works, except that field3 is required.

Comment: In your last example you render on my specific fields of the form and since you probably don't add the extra data anywhere else, the formset doesn't pass validation. In the other two examples you delegate to django the task to render the formset and the single row/form, so it takes care of adding the extra data behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer (in the docs) that coincidently explains this matter exactly as I asked my question.  The third option **must** render {{ row.id }}, otherwise Django will create the validation error.  It is up to the user to use 'style="display: none;"' in the inline html, but it **must** be rendered.

Here's the link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template

Tested and it works!